# import function from a file in the same folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I'm building a Flask app with Python 3.5 following a tutorial, based on different import rules. By looking for similar questions, I managed to solve an ImportError based on importing from a nested folder by adding the folder to the path, but I keep failing at importing a function from a script in the same folder (already in the path). The folder structure is this:

```
DoubleDibz  
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── api 
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── helloworld.py
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── common
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── constants.py
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── extensions.py
│   ├── static
│   └── templates
└── run.py
```

In app.py I import a function from config.py by using this code:

```
import config as Config
```

but I get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'config'
```

I don't understand what's the problem, being the two files in the same folder.

Comment: try with "from . import config as Config"

Comment: You need to do this `from app import config as Config`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Have you tried

```
import app.config as Config
```

It did the trick for me.

Comment: Or `from app import config as Config` depending on  your coding style

Answer (score 24):

To import from the same folder you can do:

```
from .config import function_or_class_in_config_file
```

or to import the full config with the alias as you asked:

```
from ..app import config as Config
```

Comment: This will not work if launched as a script. You would get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.config'; ' __main__' is not a package `. So @macdrai 's answer is more appropriate.

Comment: @Dr_Zaszuś, I wasn't able to import when I tried macdrai's answer and with this solution, I got the same error

Comment: Great solution if there is no need to have "app" in the first case.

Answer (score 7):

```
# imports all functions    
import config
# you invoke it this way
config.my_function()
```

or

```
# import specific function
from config import my_function
# you invoke it this way
my_function()
```

If the app.py is invoked not from the same folder you can do this:

```
# csfp - current_script_folder_path
csfp = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
if csfp not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, csfp)
# import it and invoke it by one of the ways described above
```

Answer (score 2):

Another, shorter way would be:

```
import .config as Config
```