# Error: How to import method from one file to other in a same directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using python version 3.6.1

I want to use method of one python file to another located in a same directory. I have used `from utils import wit_response` in app.py file. And when I compile it this shows an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "app.py", line 4, in 
>       from utils import wit_response
>     File "E:\Study\Python\fbmessengerbot\utils.py", line 1, in 
>       from wit import Wit
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wit'

In utils.py file I'm using `from wit import Wit`. The wit package i have already installed.

How can i resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `python -c 'import wit; print(wit)' work? And what does it print? (Assuming you are using `python`, for instance without version suffix, for your other work)

Comment: @languitar it prints '<module 'wit' from 'C:\\Users\\Mashood Murtaza\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages\\wit\\__init__.py'>'

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Virtual environment do pip freeze and check whether "wit" package is installed or not. 
If "wit" is installed open ipython and check whether you can import the "wit" package. 
If "wit" is not imported in ipython check if any dependency packages are need for "wit".

Comment: yes wit is installed with status wit==4.2.0. And i have import wit in my utils.py file

Comment: And my utils.py file works fine but when i import it to app.py it will shows an error

Comment: @MashoodMurtaza try importing like this `from .utils import method_name `

Comment: @MashoodMurtaza there is a answer which is similar to your question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43865291/import-function-from-a-file-in-the-same-folder?rq=1)