# Freshman AttributeError： No attribute in a module

Tags: python, module, attribution

just new to python, and I believe this is not a big deal but because I am a freshman.
Basically, this is a simple program plotting a FM signal in time domain. I write a module by myself.

```
def FreqMod (fc,fm,t_domain)

    pi=py.pi  
    if fc>fm:
       delta=fc-fm
    else:
        delta=fm-fc
    return py.cos(2*pi*fc*t_domain+ (delta/fm)*py.sin(2*pi*fm*t_domain))


def AmpMod(fc,fm,t_domain):

    pi=py.pi
    return py.cos(2*pi*fc*t_domain)*py.cos(2*pi*fm*t_domain)
```

And import it in another program

```
import numpy as py
import mylib 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


pi=py.pi
y=mylib.FreqMod(5,1000,t=py.arange(0,2*pi,pi/4000))
plt.plot(y)
```

The lib file is located as the same directory as the program. But I Got this later:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "...(The directory)...", line 14, in <module>
    y=mylib.FreqMod(5,1000,t=py.arange(0,2*pi,pi/4000))

AttributeError: module 'mylib' has no attribute 'FreqMod'
```

It seems like I didn't import the module successfully. I have compared it with examples in how to write and import a module, but yet can't figure out why. This really confuse me as a beginner in python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [import function from a file in the same folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43865291/import-function-from-a-file-in-the-same-folder)

Comment: Where do you use the `t_domain` parameter inside your function? and Where do you define the `global t` ? If you pass a `t` parameter  to your function, it will not know what it is. Fix those issues and I think you should have no trouble importing `mylib`

Comment: Hi. Yeah I found that there are some error related to the variables and I have fixed that. However the attribute error is still there.

Comment: As shown now  I have filtered the problem with variables.

Comment: It seems like a problem with the path. I have solved it. But anyway thanks!