# Is there a way to import a file in a sub directory with a space

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, subdirectory

[import function from a file in the same folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43865291/import-function-from-a-file-in-the-same-folder)

I got a pretty good answer in this post on how to import a file from a sub directory. But now I also want to know how to import a subdirectory that contains a space,
so from the original example in the post above; lets say that we have an identical sub directory called "app 2" and I want to import the config.py from that sub directory.

```
DoubleDibz  
├── app 2
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── api 
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── helloworld.py
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── common
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── constants.py
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── extensions.py
│   ├── static
│   └── templates
└── run.py
```

How would I go about doing this?

`import app 2.config` doesn't seem to work and adding single or double quotes does not seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

As seen in the [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9123555/14316282) of the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9123517/14316282) shared by [@truth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11117210/truth), you can do something like this:

```
_config = __import__("app 2.config")
```

Ideally a Python project would not have folder names with spaces in them, as this is method is not recommended, so if this is yours then I would suggest to just change the name of that folder to `app_2`

Comment: Sounds good, thank you.