# Python cant import module

Tags: python, module

I have two files:

File 'exceptions.py':

```
class ExecutableDoesntExistsError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, given_path_to_executable):
        self.given_path_to_executable = given_path_to_executable

    def __str__(self):
        return 'ERROR! The given path to executable %s does not exists or file absent!' % self.given_path_to_executable
```

File2:

```
import exceptions


raise exceptions.ExecutableDoesntExistsError('123')
```

I catch an error AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ExecutableDoesntExistsError' while running the second file

Comment: is the name of the first file exceptions and is it in the same folder than File2?

Comment: @Jan_B yes, it is at the same folder. The first file is called "exceptions.py"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [import function from a file in the same folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43865291/import-function-from-a-file-in-the-same-folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the name of File1 is exceptions.py and it is in the same directory as File2 → rewrite your import statement to:

```py
from exceptions import ExecutableDoesntExistsError
```

then use the class `ExecutableDoesntExistsError` without `exceptions.` prefix

Comment: I have tried, same

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name ExecutableDoesntExistsError

Comment: do you use an IDE such as Pycharm or VS Code? One of these can help with e.g. spelling mistakes on import statements. Double check that you have the names of your file and class right in both files, that they are in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to import exceptions, rather you need to import your custom exception in File2 from exceptions.py as such:

```
from exceptions import ExecutableDoesntExistsError
```

Then you just raise the custom exception like this!

```
raise  ExecutableDoesntExistsError('123')
```

Output:

```
exceptions.ExecutableDoesntExistsError: ERROR! The given path to executable 123 does not exists or file absent!
```